# Xml traversal: Alternative to recursive patterns?

Tags: xml

I have an XML document which needs to be traversed efficiently (recursively visit all nodes).

I am not sure if I am comfortable with using recursive patterns so I thought about other patterns. Am I being too paranoid, should I just use recursive pattern instead? In the past when the recursive function grew in size, it became increasingly difficult to find on which stack a runtime error had occurred, and visualizing the problem.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. You can use SAX event handlers and avoid recursion, or can use tail recursion (all the modern compilers optimize tail recursion to a loop and no stack overflow happens).

Comment: @khachik, recursively visit all nodes in the xml.

Comment: I meant: visit recursively to do what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to recursively visit all elements in an XML document, using recursion sure seems like the obvious choice.  If you're having trouble visualizing a problem because your recursive function got too large and you don't know what stack a runtime error occurred in, the problem's more likely with debugging techniques than with recursion itself.

But if you're really determined to do this, you can build a visitor object that traverses XML without using recursion.  Instead, you have to build a list (well, a hash table) of all the elements that you've visited so far.  Some pseudocode for the visitor:

```
while current_element != null:
   if current_element not in elements_visited:
      process current_element
      add current_element to elements_visited
   next_element = null
   for each child of current_element:
      if child is not in elements_visited:
         next_element = child
         break
   if next_element == null:
      next_element = current_element.parent
   current_element = next_element
```

That doesn't maintain a stack, but you pay for it with the traversal of the child axis every time you revisit an element.  (You can get around this by storing the index of the last child element visited in the entry of `elements_visited` and using that as the starting point of the loop through the child elements.  Is this complicated enough yet?)

Comment: I am doing web application functional testing using Selenium. I can't seem to use the debug mode 100% in Eclipse because the FireFox browser will not launch when going step by step in debug mode.